# Poynting Vector for a Laser

Tags: poynting-vector

How do you calculate the Poynting vector for a laser given it's power? I know for a sphere you can just take the power, and divide it by 4$\pi R^2$, but I don't know what I would do for a laser. Would I have to take into account the aperture size?

Comment: Think for a few minutes about what $4\pi R^2$ represents in the context of spheres. That should give you a good start.

Comment: You have to take into account local field configuration of a laser. The Poynting vector shows energy flux in each point of space.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is think about the UNITS of the Poynting vector - they are in W per square metre (SI units).

Hence if you have a power, somewhere you are going to need to divide by an area!

$$P = \int <{\bf S}> \cdot\, d{\bf A}\, ,$$
where $P$ is the power, $<{\bf S}>$ is the time-averaged Poynting vector and $d{\bf A}$ is an element of area (with vector direction normal to the surface area).

The situation in a laser beam is made even easier by the fact that the (vector) area and the Poynting vector are in the same direction - so no worries about scalar products.